# LightSlider Not Working on BigCartel.com Store

Tags: javascript, html, css, slider, bigcartel

I am trying to add a LightSlider image carousel with thumbnails to my Big Cartel website (to display product images) but I can't get it to work (even with example images)

I have tested it on Codepen & JSFiddle - works fine there, but on my bigcartel.com store, The photos show up stacked. No thumbnail gallery.

My Code (working): [Codepen](https://codepen.io/findingcolors/pen/rNJNmQa)

````
    width:500px;
}
.ls-slider ul {
    list-style: none outside none;
    padding-left: 0;
    margin-bottom:0;
}
.ls-slider li {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 6px;
    cursor:pointer;
}
.ls-slider li img {
    display: block;
    height: auto;
    max-width: 100%;
}```
````

Answer (score 0):

If it's working everywhere except the website, maybe it's a problem with your server. Maybe the code is messed up or the links are failing.

Comment: It would have been more appropriate to have posted this as a comment.

Comment: I have checked (via inspector) all scripts are loading.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why it didn't work, was because you are setting the lightslider controls to false: try replacing the controls to "true" rather than "false "

```
$('#lightSlider').lightSlider({
    gallery: true,
    item: 1,
    loop:true,
    slideMargin: 0,
    thumbItem: 4,
    controls: true,
});
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, but the "controls" setting is for the navigation arrows and optional. I tried anyway, but it's still not working